# Bulk URL replacement for broken Java Bug Database hyperlinks in posts

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, broken-link

Do we ever bulk update URLs?  The Java Bug Database URL format appears to have changed from http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6754672 to https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6754672.

```
- http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6754672
+ https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6754672
```

The old URLs redirect to the bug search page, not the specific bugs, so they do need to be updated.

A search for [`"http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22http%3A%2F%2Fbugs.sun.com%2Fbugdatabase%22) gives 474 results, so that's how many questions/answers that need to be updated in order to work properly.

Additionally, there appears to be an even older URL format in use: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6754672, that gives [147 search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22http%3A%2F%2Fbugs.sun.com%2Fview_bug.do%22).

```
- http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6754672
+ https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6754672
```

Is there a way to do a bulk update in a case like this, and should we?

Comment: SE staff do have a tool that can bulk update urls for simple updates, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313243/how-to-find-and-or-change-a-set-of-hyperlinks-on-a-site/314169#314169

Comment: And if SE staff doesn't respond to a request to use that tool (or declines it) then you could also try to get a group of people together and edit all posts manually, similar to [tag burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) (but much simpler).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks.  I've expanded this into part of an answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424733/1108305

Comment: Discovered yet another, apparently older URL format: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6182950. I've added it to the question.

Comment: Community bot needs to chill out about replacing the links here :)

Comment: @M-- Thanks for reverting the links. :-)  I fixed it (twice) in [Feature request: Rewrite Java Bug Database links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424735/1108305), but forgot about this one.

Answer (score 6):

[A comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424728/bulk-url-replacement-for-broken-java-bug-hyperlinks-in-posts?noredirect=1#comment957847_424728) on this question by user [Abdul Aziz Barkat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14991864/abdul-aziz-barkat) links to a Meta Stack Exchange post ([How to find and/or change a set of hyperlinks on a site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313243/308327)) explaining that an internal tool does exist to bulk rewrite links:

> There exists, internally, a search-and-replace tool for rewriting links. It's very simple; if someone changes their entire URL scheme, it's not much help. But for stuff like this, where we can simply cut out one consistent part of each URL and drop in another... It works pretty well.
>
> If you need this - and I'd consider anything over 100 links a need - post a feature-request on the appropriate site meta and we'll try & get it done.

Since there are over 400 results with Java Bug Database URLs, that meets the stated threshold for whether there's a need.

As of 9 hours after asking this Stack Overflow Meta question, there are currently 16 upvotes and no downvotes.  It's apparent that there's therefore community consensus that this bulk change should be done.

I've created a feature request to bulk update these URLs: [Feature request: Rewrite Java Bug Database links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424735/1108305).

Update: the bulk update was performed on 11/10/2023.