# Feature request: Rewrite Java Bug Database links

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks

This post is a request for the Stack Overflow team to use the internal link rewriting tool described in Meta Stack Exchange answer [How to find and/or change a set of hyperlinks on a site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/308327) to bulk update Java Bug Database URLs in posts.

> If you need this - and I'd consider anything over 100 links a need - post a feature-request on the appropriate site meta and we'll try & get it done.

The URL scheme for Java Bug Database links appears to have changed from http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6754672 to https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6754672.

```
- http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6754672
+ https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6754672
```

There is also an even older URL format of http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6754672 in use on Stack Overflow.

Some URLs have an additional (unused) `jsessionid` in the URL, e.g. `http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=36649bcae69963754fe1bd095030?bug_id=4671142`.  Ideally it would be removed, but if that isn't straightforward to do, it can be left in without causing any issues.

Apparent consensus reached in meta post ([Bulk URL replacement for broken Java Bug Database hyperlinks in posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424728/1108305)) discussing this is to update these links.

A search for [`"http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22http%3A%2F%2Fbugs.sun.com%2Fbugdatabase%2Fview_bug.do%22) gives 474 results, which is large enough to request use of the tool, per the Meta Stack Exchange answer.  Likewise, a search for [`"http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22http%3A%2F%2Fbugs.sun.com%2Fview_bug.do%22) gives 147 search results.  Searching for this text within Markdown hyperlinks yields many more results: ([Feature request: Rewrite Java Bug Database links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424735/feature-request-rewrite-java-bug-database-links?noredirect=1#comment957892_424735)).

Please run the link rewriter to update Java Bug Database URLs in questions and answers.

Specifically, make the following URL replacements:

```
http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do
=>
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug

http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do
=>
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug
```

These links also appear on [other Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?page=1&q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2fbugs.sun.com%2fbugdatabase%22&pagesize=50).  Ideally we would fix links network-wide, rather than just for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is better suited as an answer to your existing question.

Comment: No. We can't status-review answers, and even then, an (at the time) CM explicitly asked for a feature-request question

Comment: Please be *very explicit* as to what you see that should be changed. Right now you're just giving two example URLs (which is a good thing to also do), but you haven't articulated the *exact* changes, from a programmatic point of view, which you are requesting. Thus, you're **assuming** that the person looking at this will see the same differences you're seeing. For example, it appears from your first example that you're asking for the origin of all links starting with `http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase` to be changed from `http://bugs.sun.com/` to `https://bugs.java.com`.

Comment: But, for example, that doesn't take into account that there's quite a number of URLs which are `http://bugs.sun.com/`, but not `http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase`. What should be done with those?

Comment: @M.Justin: I'd suggest editing your question as a whole to read as if it were always the best version of itself (i.e. so that the URL formats to replace are listed together), rather than listing the additional URL format at the end – that way, it's easier for the devs to understand all of the changes need to be made. (If you put it at the end, the other URL to be replaced might accidentally get missed.)

Comment: @V2Blast OK.  I'm in the middle of an edit adding the info now.  I'll finish that up and then do a second pass.

Comment: Your estimate of the number of posts which contain these URLs is substantially low. To find text in links, you need to use `url:` in the search field. To find all occurrences, you need to search in all three of [`url:"http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase"`](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fbugs.sun.com%2Fbugdatabase%22) (1,252), [`"http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase"`](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22http%3A%2F%2Fbugs.sun.com%2Fbugdatabase%22) (474), & [`code:"http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase"`](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fbugs.sun.com%2Fbugdatabase%22) (103).

Comment: In addition, there are a number of hits for [`url:"http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase"`](https://stackexchange.com/search?page=1&q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2fbugs.sun.com%2fbugdatabase%22&pagesize=50) on other SE sites. Should these be changed on the other sites too? Presumably, they should also be changed on those sites.

Comment: Can the link rewriter remove the extraneous `;jsessionid=[0-9a-f]+` for URLs that have it, or are we better off just leaving it in there? `https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=36649bcae69963754fe1bd095030?bug_id=4671142`

Comment: @Makyen Would the request to fix this network-wide be a request per site meta?  A single request in Meta Stack Exchange?  Part of this ticket in Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: @M.Justin: It's a simple find-and-replace function, as described in the linked MSE post – no wildcards are possible. That said, if those links still work fine and aren't actually broken, it's not really worth including that in the request anyway. (And it's fine to note that a few posts on other sites could benefit from the link replacement when you make the request; the devs' link-replacement tool can be used to check all sites anyway.)

Comment: @V2Blast Thanks for the explanation.  The MSE answer itself doesn't say that it's a strict find/replace, just that it's very simple and works for those.  That it's a strict find/replace is mentioned in your comment on that question (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313243/how-to-find-and-or-change-a-set-of-hyperlinks-on-a-site/314169#comment1252928_313243), as well as in other MSE questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375122/308327

Comment: @V2Blast For the SE internal ticket, is the question copied over at the time the [meta-tag:status-review] tag is added (shortly after that), or is it just the question title and link to the question (or a dynamic text)? I ask, because the first version of this question was the one to which the status-review tag was added, but subsequent edits made it *much* better as a request for developer action. In other words, should we immediately add the status-review tag or wait (a short time) when it looks like good edits will substantially improve things very soon (but not wait for perfection)?

Comment: @Makyen: The internal issue on our end is created when the status-review tag is added. That issue includes the title of the post, the site it's from, the text of the post, and a link to the post. (If the post's title is changed, it'll create a new issue on our end.) That said, we can always edit the issue (or comment on it) as needed to clarify the request. ...So ideally, you should make sure the post is in its final/best state before adding the [status-review] tag – but if some necessary/useful edits are made after the tag has already been added, that's okay.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for your patience on this one. All of the links have been updated.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm gonna roll back the automatic update of the links in this request for link fixing.  That's just confusing. :-)

Comment: A quick search of the site makes it look like the `http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do` links were updated, but the even older `http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do` links were not.  Is that correct?

Comment: Should I create a new feature request for the `http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do` links that were not updated?

Comment: @M.Justin Let me check with the dev who handled it to see if the second one didn't go through.

Comment: @M.Justin Should be good now.

Comment: That looks much better.  Thanks for the quick turnaround!